# Xdebug 3 couldn't connect from Docker [20.10.12 | rootless mode] to PhpStorm debug client. Ubuntu

Tags: php, docker, apache, phpstorm, xdebug

So, my configurations are:

1. Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1-apache as php_base
COPY --from=mlocati/php-extension-installer /usr/bin/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/
RUN a2enmod rewrite && install-php-extensions pgsql
RUN echo 'ServerName localhost' >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf && service apache2 restart
WORKDIR /var/www/lessor-calculator

FROM php_base as php_dev
RUN pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
```

2. docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: "3.4"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: docker/server
      target: php_dev
    networks:
      my-network:
    environment:
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=MyApp"
    ports:
      - "${DOCKER_SERVER_PORT:-9180}:80"
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/lessor-calculator
      - ./docker/server/apache/sites-enabled:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ./docker/server/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
      - ./docker/server/php/conf.d/xdebug.log:/var/log/xdebug.log
      - ./docker/server/php/conf.d/error_reporting.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/error_reporting.ini
```

3. `xdebug_info()` output:

[image: xdebug_info_screenshot]

4. PhpStorm settings:

[image: phpstorm_php_interpreter_screenshot]

[image: phpstorm_xdebug_settings_screenshot]

5. Xdebug log:

```
[17] Log opened at 2022-01-04 14:47:45.645181
[17] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: host.docker.internal:9003.
[17] [Step Debug] WARN: Creating socket for 'host.docker.internal:9003', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
[17] [Step Debug] ERR: Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(
[17] Log closed at 2022-01-04 14:47:45.649491
```

Also I've tried to use another port, `curl host.docker.internal:9000`, with answer "Connection refused", (but just ping `host.docker.internal` is work fine). Everyone said, that there's no need to map 9000 port.
Please any suggestion, what reason could be. Thank you.

UPDATE: Xdebug conf:

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug

[xdebug]
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.log="/var/log/xdebug.log"
```

Update: new configuration for 9003 port, enable xdebug.log

Update 2: i'm using rootless docker. And i've checked it's all work in rootfull mode.

Comment: *"Everyone said, that there's no need to map 9000 port."* That is correct. You do not need `expose:      - "9000"` as this is what causes it. One of the most common mistakes with Xdebug: it's Xdebug that connects to the IDE and NOT other way around. Xdebug connection is an **outgoing** and NOT *incoming*. With your current settings (9000 port that is exposed) you are trying to connect back to the docker container itself. Plus the IDE cannot listen on that port.

Comment: The way to go for now: 1) get rid of `expose:      - "9000"`; 2) Better use default `9003` port for Xdebug comms (either edit it here `xdebug.client_port=9000` or remove the line completely since it's a default port since Xdebug v3). 3) Restart/rebuild your container to have those changes. 4) If you activate "phone handle" icon in PhpStorm (that simply starts listening for incoming debug connections on those ports), you can then check with `netstat` or whatever tool is in your host OS to ensure that it's PhpStorm that listens on TCP 9003 Xdebug port and not another app.

Comment: If there are still issues: post updated info + enable Xdebug log and share it (that's if connecting works but debugger does not stop etc).

Comment: @LazyOne, have change xdebug.ini to, and move port to 9003
`zend_extension=xdebug
[xdebug]
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.log="/var/log/xdebug.log"`
Still couldn't connect.

Comment: @LazyOne, have update question body with new configuration and xdebug log.

Comment: **1)** With these settings it _should_ work. I'm not a Linux user, maybe something else is involved (like a firewall)... The same would work OK here on Windows (as far as I remember when I tested it). **2)** So what about ports? What app is listening there? If you exit PhpStorm and **check 9003** with `netstat` or alike -- will it show any app using it? If yes -- that's should not be like that. If not -- launch PhpStorm and check again -- still no app? if there is app listed -- what app is that?

Comment: **3)** Just in case -- if you use `xdebug.discover_client_host = true` -- will it make any difference?  4) Do you have PHP on your host OS by any chance? If you do -- are you able to xdebug PHP there (local PHP script)? This is just to check that host/PhpStorm side of things is OK. 5) What IP protocol (better say versions) you have got there? Please ensure that IPv4 is the main one. You may need to disable IPv6 (seen such suggestions before for Linux hosts) . It could be that the host names resolves to some wrong IP/some network config issue...

Comment: P.S. Can try a TeamViewer session. It may give some clues this way when seeing it all with own eyes...

Comment: So, did you managed to make it work?

Comment: @LazyOne, sorry i've a break for a day :)
1) i've tried xdebug.discover_client_host = true already, it makes no difference
2) 9003 port is listening only whtn PhpStorm is run
3) I've checked on local apache+xdebug3+php8.1, it works fine
4) TeamViewer session would be great)
5) Firewall disabled

Comment: Also yet i've make this instructions https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#enable-forwarding-from-docker-containers-to-the-outside-world

Comment: I've checked outgoing connections, it's seems strange, i can curl google.com (i can't see trace, most part of traceroute is hidden), but at same time i can't curl 172.17.0.1... at any port

Comment: And, oh... i suggest now, it can be important: i'm using rootless docker

Comment: Yes, same configuration works fine in rootfull docker, so it's seems i (we ;D) something missed up in rootless configuration, but what...

Comment: *"something missed up in rootless configuration, but what..."* Sorry, cannot help here. I've used Docker Desktop only on my Windows machine (where it works just fine with _default settings_). "rootless docker" -- zero clues from my end (I've read a mention about it in some article but that's about it). But this issue (the reason) reminds me of Apache on Linux when SELinux is used -- you need to enable connections (`sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1`) otherwise Xdebug will simply not work... P.S. I hope you will successfully sort out your rootless Docker config :)

Answer (score 0):

It worked on my case:

> PHP 8.2.8 (cli) (built: Jul  8 2023 07:10:21) (NTS) Copyright (c) The
> PHP Group Zend Engine v4.2.8, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
> with Zend OPcache v8.2.8, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
> with Xdebug v3.2.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2023, by Derick Rethans

In the docker-compose.yaml file there is 2 line that should be reconfigured like below

```
XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-debug}'
XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=172.26.174.72}'
```

as @LazyOne figured out,
If we are using VSCode remote connection to WSL (source code put in WSL) then client_host will be wsl's IP. If VSCode opens the workspace directly then it must be machine's IP(Host Machine).

Additional:

To find IP run ifconfig, ipconfig, or some command like this on your target environment terminal.

Run `Sail php -m`  in WSL to check if xdebug is installed on Docker Container or not.

If not run `Sail artisan sail:publish` to create a docker folder in the source code. then config DockerFile for xdebug installation

After Reconfigure docker-compose.yaml run `Sail stop` then `sail up --build` to re-create all container.

Add `pathMappings` in launch.json:

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "externalConsole": false,
            "ignore": [
                "**/vendor/**/*.php"
            ],
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html": "/home/abcUser/laravelTut/firstApp/firstapp", // Map your WSL path to the container path
              },
        },
```

Updating:
Don't know why but after update Wsl extension I got Port Forward tab in VSCode and if I start Debug named "Listen for Xdebug" as defined above VScode created Port forward to localhost:9003 and it make

> SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=172.26.174.72
> setting not working anymore.

Instead, 2 things may need to be changed
In docker-Compose.yml:

> XDEBUG_CONFIG:'${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'

In launch.json, add host name:

> "hostname": "localhost",

Answer (score -1):

Why not expose the desired port with eg. `EXPOSE 9003` in `Dockerfile`?

`xdebug` ports and `Dockerfile` ports need to match.

Comment: As i've understand and as @LazyOne has said in first comment, "expose" is instruction to listen incoming connections (from local machine to docker container), but xdebug generate outgoing tcp-requests inside container (and send them from docker container to local machine)

Comment: It's Xdebug that connects to IDE and NOT other way around, so it's an **outgoing** connection (one of the most common mistakes when dealing with Xdebug). If you expose Xdebug port in Docker then your IDE is unable to listen on that port (as it will be used by Docker that forwards **incoming** requests into the container)